# python imaplib ssl proton bridge login failed

Tags: python, ssl, imaplib

In linux, trying to login to a protonmail account from python using imaplib, ssl, and protonmail-bridge

I was originally having an SSL problem but that may/may not be fixed.
Currently, I am receiving an error at the login (see below for error).

Any thoughts on what is causing this error and how to fix it?

TIA

```
#!/usr/bin/python3                                                                                                                                                                                                 
import imaplib
import ssl

usern="username"
passw="password"
bridge_certificate="cert.pem"


sslctx = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
sslctx.options &= ~ssl.OP_NO_SSLv3
sslctx.load_verify_locations(cafile=bridge_certificate)
sslctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_OPTIONAL
sslctx.check_hostname = False

imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("localhost", 1143, ssl_context=sslctx)
imap = imaplib.IMAP4("localhost", 1143) 
print(imap.welcome) 
imap.starttls(ssl_context=sslctx) 
try: 
    imap.login(usern, passw) 
    print("Logged in as %r !" % usern) 
except: 
    imaplib.errno 
    print("Log in failed.")
```

b'* OK [CAPABILITY IDLE IMAP4rev1 MOVE STARTTLS UIDPLUS UNSELECT] Proton Mail Bridge 03.00.21 - gluon session ID 18'

Log in failed. imaplib.IMAP4.error: command SELECT illegal in state NONAUTH, only allowed in states AUTH, SELECTED

My original syntax was

```
sslctx = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
sslctx.options &= ~ssl.OP_NO_SSLv3
sslctx.load_verify_locations(cafile=bridge_certificate)
sslctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_OPTIONAL
sslctx.check_hostname = False

imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("localhost", 1143, ssl_context=sslctx)
imap.login(usern, passw)
try: 
    imap.login(usern, passw) 
    print("Logged in as %r !" % usern) 
except: 
    imaplib.errno 
    print("Log in failed.")
```

and I was given the following suggestion

proton bridge sends the plain IMAP welcome message on connect, since it is expecting TLS only after STARTTLS. This IMAP welcome message then gets misinterpreted as TLS ServerHello, which results in the SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER error you see.

The fix is not to use imaplib.IMAP4_SSL but instead imaplib.IMAP4 together with starttls, i.e. something like this:

imap = imaplib.IMAP4("localhost", 1143)
imap.starttls(ssl_context=sslctx)

Comment: The explanation you received and the suggested solution seem reasonable. Have you tried it?

Comment: It clearly shows that the login failed, after successful upgrade to TLS. Use IMAP4.error to and IMAP4.debug to find out why the login failed, maybe the server provides some more detailed error message. Make also sure that you actually provide the correct credentials. Look especially out for any encoding in the credentials in case you are not fully use ASCII or for any white space or new lines which accidentally might be in the credentials you use but which don't belong there.